# stopping a task by removing the process id in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. I have the following task:

```
- name: Run mock server on port 4000
  shell: |
    sudo cd "{{ travis.base_build_path }}/mock-server"
    sudo npm run start
```

and after I need to stop this task by removing process id. How can I do that?
Can I name the above process some how stop it in another task?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like an Ansible-specific task. I would do this with systemd: create a systemd unit for this 'npm run start'.

```
- systemd: name=your_unit.service state=started
- debug: msg="do something"
- systemd: name=your_unit.service state=stopped
```

More information on systemd units is here:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html